# How can I create one method called with different object types call a strongly typed method with that parameter?

Tags: generics, polymorphism, signature

I currently have two methods, identical except for the object type being passed in and a method call using that object.

Objects IN:

- PostmarkMessage
- TempatedPostmarkMessage

Method call (accepts either object type)

- client.SendMessageAsync(<PostmarkMessage or TemplatedPostmarkMessage>)

How can I make this one method, if this is even possible?

```cs
    public static async Task<bool> SendPostmarkMessage(PostmarkMessage postmarkMessage)
    {
        var client = new PostmarkClient(ServiceConfig.PostmarkClientId);

        var messageSent = false;

        var retries = 0;

        while(retries < 5 && !messageSent)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.SendMessageAsync(postmarkMessage);

                if(response.Status == PostmarkStatus.Success)
                {
                    messageSent = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LogEvent(
                        LogLevel.Warn,
                        ServiceLogger,
                        $"Postmark response: {response.Message}"
                    );

                    LogEvent(
                        LogLevel.Warn,
                        ServiceLogger,
                        $"Sending Postmark message failed. Retrying..."
                    );

                    retries++;

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvent(
                    LogLevel.Warn,
                    ServiceLogger,
                    $"Postmark response: {ex.Message}"
                );

                LogEvent(
                    LogLevel.Warn,
                    ServiceLogger,
                    $"Sending Postmark message failed. Retrying..."
                );

                retries++;

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }

        return messageSent;
    }

    public static async Task<bool> SendPostmarkMessage(TemplatedPostmarkMessage templatedPostmarkMessage)
    {
        var client = new PostmarkClient(ServiceConfig.PostmarkClientId);

        var messageSent = false;

        var retries = 0;

        while(retries < 5 && !messageSent)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.SendMessageAsync(templatedPostmarkMessage);

                if(response.Status == PostmarkStatus.Success)
                {
                    messageSent = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LogEvent(
                        LogLevel.Warn,
                        ServiceLogger,
                        $"Postmark response: {response.Message}"
                    );

                    LogEvent(
                        LogLevel.Warn,
                        ServiceLogger,
                        $"Sending Postmark message failed. Retrying..."
                    );

                    retries++;

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvent(
                    LogLevel.Warn,
                    ServiceLogger,
                    $"Postmark response: {ex.Message}"
                );

                LogEvent(
                    LogLevel.Warn,
                    ServiceLogger,
                    $"Sending Postmark message failed. Retrying..."
                );

                retries++;

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }

        return messageSent;
    }
```

I tried creating a generic method but do not understand how to convert the generic object to the strongy-typed object that the method requires.